# font color changed when converted to pdf from html/css using itext and flying-saucer

Tags: html, css, itext, bold

I overview the html with css in chrome, it looks normal as follows:

html:[image]

while pdf looked dislike the same as follows:

pdf:[image]

pdf2: [image]

As you see in pdf2, the font is not bold, but outlined with black color。And my code snippet here:

```css
.title{
 font-size: 2em;
 color: #4d82bf;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <p class="title">报告书总览 Summary Overview</p>
```

Does anybody know how to make the html and pdf displayed the same with bold font?

**TIP:** 
without the font-weight `font-weight: bold;`style, they look the same:

html: [image]
pdf:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching a few hours, I found this question [Can't change bold text color, a 'black border' remains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777306/cant-change-bold-text-color-a-black-border-remains/23777582#23777582)
 which answered by @Bruno Lowagie, the creator of iText. According to the accepted answer, a couterpart bold font(.ttf) file is needed. After adding 'msyhbd.ttf' to the ItextRender, my program worked well! Thanks to @Bruno Lowagie
, and hope this post would help anybody! Results as follows:

[image]

Comment: Great that you added your own answer after you've found the solution. This helps others which have the same problem. So welcome to SO!